# Need help combining SQL queries

Tags: sql, pervasive

```
SELECT 
    tableA.col1,
    tableA.col2,
    LEFT(tableB.col3, 4) as person

FROM tableA

LEFT JOIN tableB ON

    tableB.col1 = tableA.col1 AND
    tableB.col2 = tableA.col2

WHERE tableA.col3 = '000000'

AND tableA.col4 <> ''

AND person = 'Zeus'

ORDER BY tableA.col1, tableA.col4 ASC;

---

col1          col4        person
001           abc         Zeus
002           abc         Zeus
003           xyz         Zeus
004           xyz         Zeus
```

+

```
SELECT
    tableC.col1,
    SUM(tableC.col2) as cost

FROM tableC

WHERE tableC.col3 = 'L'

GROUP BY tableC.col1, tableC.col3;

---

col1          cost
001           23462
002           25215
003           92381
004           29171
```

=

```
col1          col4          person          cost
001           abc           Zeus            23462
002           abc           Zeus            25215
003           xyz           Zeus            92381
004           xyz           Zeus            29171
```

How do I do this? I tried putting the second query as a nested select in the top one, but I couldn't get it to work. Both result sets share the same `col1` values, which are unique, so I guess they need to be joined on that? And ultimately the `person` is where the query will differ every time I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with an inner join on col1

```
SELECT tableA.col1, tableA.col2, LEFT(tableB.col3, 4) as person, tableC.col1, SUM(tableC.col2) as cost
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON ( tableB.col1 = tableA.col1 AND tableB.col2 = tableA.col2)
INNER JOIN tableC ON ( tableA.col1 = tableC.col1)
WHERE tableA.col3 = '000000'
AND tableA.col4 <> ''
AND person = 'Zeus'
GROUP BY tableA.col4, person, tableC.col1, tableC.col3;
ORDER BY tableA.col1, tableA.col4 ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want combin your queries you can set alias for your queries like this query

```
select * from example ... as table1;
```

and you have your select result in table1 so you can set alias for your other select in your question

```
SELECT
    tableC.col1,
    SUM(tableC.col2) as cost

FROM tableC

WHERE tableC.col3 = 'L'

GROUP BY tableC.col1, tableC.col3 as table2
```

now you can use join or other commands on table1 and table in your question

```
join can give you preffered result.
SELECT 
    table1.*,
    table2.*   
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON
    table1.col1 = table2.col1
ORDER BY table1.col1
```

Comment: I never knew you could set an alias on a query! That's going to be very helpful in the near future. Thank you much.